# About straight lines and null sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to proof the following statement: Given a null set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we can always find a straight line going through the origin namely $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f^{-1}(X)$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}$.

I guess the idea should be to aim for a contradiction but I cannot conclude.

Comment: Can you prove the claim if instead of "straight line through the origin" it had said "straight line parallel to the $x$-axis"?

Comment: I am not sure. I guess the idea is to show that there are some "small" intervals contained in $X$ and after that one should try to build a small cube inside $X$?